# Разделение строк в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеются грязные данные в столбце `DataFrame.ip` формата:

```
 '5.77.29.7'
 '217.118.83.250'
 '46.20.176.92'
 '213.87.135.38'
 '213.87.131.254'
 '185.79.102.50'
 '83.220.238.131, 80.240.105.237'
 '217.118.83.252'
 '213.87.130.157, 185.79.102.38'
```

Очевидно, необходимо разделить строки с двумя ip-адресами через запятую на отдельные строки, чтобы получилось

```
 '5.77.29.7'
 '217.118.83.250'
 '46.20.176.92'
 '213.87.135.38'
 '213.87.131.254'
 '185.79.102.50'
 '83.220.238.131' 
 '80.240.105.237'
 '217.118.83.252'
 '213.87.130.157' 
 '185.79.102.38'
```

Как это аккуратно сделать?

Comment: Ваши реальные данные именно так и выглядят - в одиночных кавычках? И в результате вы хотите получить по одному IP в строке обрамленному в кавычки и с запятой в конце - я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Все верно. Адреса в одиночных кавычках, в одиночных кавычках их можно оставить, все равно потом они прибавляются к строке url по которой идет парсинг

Comment: почему в последней строке в результате нет запятой в конце?

Comment: Просто так представил, в общем это столбец DataFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [explode()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/5741205).

Исходный DF:

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]:
                                 ip  num
0                       '5.77.29.7'   93
1                  '217.118.83.250'   63
2                    '46.20.176.92'   82
3                   '213.87.135.38'   90
4                  '213.87.131.254'   22
5                   '185.79.102.50'   59
6  '83.220.238.131, 80.240.105.237'   16
7                  '217.118.83.252'   46
8   '213.87.130.157, 185.79.102.38'   55
```

Решение:

```
res = explode(df.assign(ip=df['ip'].str.replace("'", "").str.split('\,\s*')), 'ip')
```

Результат:

```
In [61]: res
Out[61]:
    num              ip
0    93       5.77.29.7
1    63  217.118.83.250
2    82    46.20.176.92
3    90   213.87.135.38
4    22  213.87.131.254
5    59   185.79.102.50
6    16  83.220.238.131
7    16  80.240.105.237
8    46  217.118.83.252
9    55  213.87.130.157
10   55   185.79.102.38
```

Comment: res = это результирующий DataFrame? Будет нормально, если я выполню переприсвоение df.ip = explode(.....)?

Comment: @StepanSokol, `explode()` возвращает DataFrame, поэтому надо присваивать всему DF: `df = explode(df.assign(...))`

Comment: Шикарная функция, спасибо!