# Маппинг значений списка по DataFrame

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe

[Вопрос-следствие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947948/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-dataframe/947961?noredirect=1#comment1578954_947961): Есть список списков с IP-адресами и сопутствующей информацией, при этом сам ip-адрес всегда стоит под индексом [0], а остальная информация идет после, причем ее количество различно:

```
lst= [['188.234.164.151',
  'ADDRESS:        STR. SHOSSE KOSMONAVTOV, 111, BLDG. 43, OFFICE 527',
  'ADDRESS:        CJSC "ER-TELECOM HOLDING" TOMSK BRANCH',
  "ADDRESS:        614099 PERM'",
  'ADDRESS:        RUSSIAN FEDERATION',
  'ADDRESS:        SHOSSE KOSMONAVTOV, 111'],
 ['93.91.166.42',
  'PERSON:         NOC OF AVANTEL',
  'ADDRESS:        RUSSIA, 630132, NOVOSIBIRSK',
  'PERSON:         VLADISLAV SHASHKOV',
  'ADDRESS:        NARYMSKAYA STR. 27',
  'ADDRESS:        JSC AVANTEL',
  'PERSON:         LOZHNIKOV ALEXEY'],
 ['194.85.126.48',
  'ADDRESS:        CENTER OF FINANCIAL TECHNOLOGIES INC.',
  'ADDRESS:        630055 NOVOSIBIRSK',
  'PERSON:         ALEXANDR LOPATIN',
  'ADDRESS:        2 SHATURSKAYA STR.']]
```

Есть `DataFrame`, в котором тоже есть поле `ip`. 
Нужно создать столбец с контактной информацией по ip-адресам так, чтобы например строке со значением `ip`:

```
 '188.234.164.151'
```

соответствовала ячейка с информацией:

```
  STR. SHOSSE KOSMONAVTOV, 111, BLDG. 43, OFFICE 527,
  CJSC "ER-TELECOM HOLDING" TOMSK BRANCH,
  614099 PERM', RUSSIAN FEDERATION, SHOSSE KOSMONAVTOV, 111
```

Пробовал `np.where()`, увы, не рабочее решение.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе то, что хотите получить на выходе? Например в третьем списке `PERSON:` находится в середине адреса - как это должно выглядеть на выходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def parse_addr(l):
    pat = r'^\w+:\s*(.*)$'
    return ', '.join([re.sub(pat, r'\1', x) for x in l])

df = pd.DataFrame([[x[0], parse_addr(x[1:])] for x in lst], columns=['ip','address'])
```

Результат:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
                ip                                                                                                                                                address
0  188.234.164.151  STR. SHOSSE KOSMONAVTOV, 111, BLDG. 43, OFFICE 527, CJSC "ER-TELECOM HOLDING" TOMSK BRANCH, 614099 PERM', RUSSIAN FEDERATION, SHOSSE KOSMONAVTOV, 111
1     93.91.166.42                                     NOC OF AVANTEL, RUSSIA, 630132, NOVOSIBIRSK, VLADISLAV SHASHKOV, NARYMSKAYA STR. 27, JSC AVANTEL, LOZHNIKOV ALEXEY
2    194.85.126.48                                                        CENTER OF FINANCIAL TECHNOLOGIES INC., 630055 NOVOSIBIRSK, ALEXANDR LOPATIN, 2 SHATURSKAYA STR.
```